# How to put kendo validator message span element underneath the input being validated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, html.beginform, kendo-validator

I'm trying to figure this out for a while.
All the examples I saw, use the `html` with `input` and `span` elements manually inserted

I have the following code that generate form and its `datepicker` elements dynamically:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reload", "FileDate", FormMethod.Post, new { returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl, id = "DateForm", onsubmit = "return ValidateDate();" } ))
{
     @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("Date")
        .Value(Session["FileDate"] == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(Session["FileDate"].ToString()))
        .Events(e => e
               .Change("datepicker_change")
        )
     )
     @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)

     <script>
          function datepicker_change() {
                if(ValidateDate()){
                     $("#DateForm").submit();
                }
          }
     </script>
  }
```

When form is generated, I have the following code on the page:

[image]

This is a validation:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#mainMenu").kendoMenu();
            $("#Date").attr('required', 'required');
            $("#Date").attr('data-WrongFormat-msg', 'Date Format is Wrong');
            var validator = $("#container").kendoValidator({
                    rules: {
                    WrongFormat: function (input) {
                        if (input.is("[data-role=datepicker]")) {
                            var dateBox = input.data("kendoDatePicker");
                            return input.data("kendoDatePicker").value();
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        });
        function ValidateDate()
        {
            var validator = $("#container").data("kendoValidator");
            if (validator.validate()) {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

When I provide the incorrect input or no input at all, I get the correct message in the `span`. However, this span section modifies the layout of the page:[image]

How can I fix that, so my `error span` is placed underneath my form, the way it is shown in some examples like here: http://dojo.telerik.com/ikUfu:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. The problems seems to be that the validation message span element is in the wrong place for DatePickers. It is inside this element:

but, in all other widgets, it's inside the spam element one level higher:

So, it seems this is a bug in Telerik at the moment. It works for other widgets, but not for DatePicker. I'll see and find if this bug is already reported, and if not, report it. If you desperately need it fixed asap, I assume you could try some jquery magic to move the span element.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced it too. Is there any proper solution for this issue?

My workaround in a nutshell:

1. Delete all possible old error messages
2. Move the new one into the proper HTML container

   ```
   <div id="div_id">
       <input id="input_id" type="text">
   </div>

   <script>    
       var validatable = $("[id='input_id'").kendoValidator({
         rules: {
           minimumLengthRule: function (input) {
             var trimmedInputValue = $.trim(input.val());
             return trimmedInputValue.length > 0 ;
           }
         },
         messages: {
           minimumLengthRule: "The input length is too short."
         }
       }).data("kendoValidator");

       validatable.bind("validateInput", function (e) {
         $("#div_id > span").not(':first').remove();                       // 1.
         if (!e.valid) {
             $("[id='input_id_validationMessage'").appendTo('#div_id');    // 2.
         }
       });
   </script>
   ```